# Update composer zendframework packages to laminas

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, composer, zend-framework

On `composer outdated` I found several lines similar to this

> Package zendframework/zend-view is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-view instead.

How can I switch from zendframework to laminas?

Currently using version 2.3.4

Answer (score 3):

Zend Framework has been outdated however Magento 2.3.4 still references Zend Framework rather than swapping to the now supported Laminas Framework. There's nothing for you to do here, better to wait for Magento to resolve it. See [Github issue here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26335)